# Do not Update the Values in Merge statement if old values do not change while update in Merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

```
MERGE PFM_EventPerformance_MetaData AS TARGET
USING
(
    SELECT
         [InheritanceMeterID] = @InheritanceMeterPointID
        ,[SubHourlyScenarioResourceID] = @SubHourlyScenarioResourceID
        ,[MeterID] = @MeterID--internal ID
        ,[BaselineID] = @BaselineID--internal ID                            
        ,[UpdateUtc] = GETUTCDATE()
) 
AS SOURCE ON
    TARGET.[SubHourlyScenarioResourceID] = SOURCE.[SubHourlyScenarioResourceID]
    AND TARGET.[MeterID] = SOURCE.[MeterID]--internal ID
    AND TARGET.[BaselineID] = SOURCE.[BaselineID]--internal ID
WHEN MATCHED  THEN UPDATE SET
     @MetaDataID = TARGET.ID--get preexisting ID when exists (must populate one row at a time)              
   ,InheritanceMeterID = SOURCE.InheritanceMeterID                      
    ,[UpdateUtc] = SOURCE.[UpdateUtc]
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT
    (
         [InheritanceMeterID]
        ,[SubHourlyScenarioResourceID]
        ,[MeterID]--internal ID
        ,[BaselineID]--internal ID                          
    )
    VALUES
    (
         SOURCE.[InheritanceMeterID]
        ,SOURCE.[SubHourlyScenarioResourceID]
        ,SOURCE.[MeterID]--internal ID
        ,SOURCE.[BaselineID]--internal ID                           
    );
```

In the above query I do not want to update the values in the Target table if there is no change in old values. I am not sure how to achieve this as I have used Merge statement rarely. Please help me with the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not just add a condition to `WHEN MATCHED AND someconditionhere THEN UPDATE`?

Comment: Can you provide me some example code @Charlieface

Comment: I just did. But I'm not sure what you want, it's not clear. The `WHEN MATCHED` can have an extra condition if you want. We could do eg: `WHEN MATCHED AND target.InheritanceMeterID <> source.InheritanceMeterID AND target.UpdateUtc <> source.UpdateUtc THEN UPDATE SET...`

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed @Charlieface

Answer (score 0):

This is done best in two stages.

Stage 1: Merge Update on condition

[SO Answer from before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924238/merge-conditional-when-matched-then-update) (Thanks to @Laurence!)

Stage 2: hash key condition to compare

Limits: max 4000 characters, including column separator characters

A rather simple way to compare multiple columns in one condition is the use of a computed column on both sides that HASHBYTES( , <column(s)> ) generates.

This moves writing lots of code from the merge statement to the table generation.

Quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
  id_column  int   NOT NULL,
  dsc_name1  varchar(100),
  dsc_name2  varchar(100),
  num_age    tinyint,
  flg_hash   AS HashBytes( 'SHA1', 
      Cast( dsc_name1 AS nvarchar(4000) ) 
      + N'•' + dsc_name2 + N'•' + Cast( num_age AS nvarchar(3) )
      ) PERSISTED
)
;
```

Comparing columns flg_hash between source and destination will make comparison quick as it is just a comparison between two 20 bit varbinary columns.

Couple of Caveat Emptor for working with [HashBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

- Function only works for a total of 4000 nvarchar characters
- Trade off for short comparison code lies in generation of correct order in views and tables
- There is a duplicate collision chance of around an [2^50+ for SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) - as security mechanism this is now considered insecure and a few years ago MS tried to drop SHA1 as algorithm
- Added columns to tables and views can be overlooked from comparison if hash bytes code is outside of consideration for amendments
- Overall I found that when comparing multiple columns this can overload my server engines but never had an issue with hash key comparisons